# How to return customized query result in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

User Table

```
+------------+
|    User    |
+------------+
| uid        |
| name       |
| created_at |
| updated_at |
+------------+
```

Car Table

```
+------------+
|    Car     |
+------------+
| cid        |
| uid        |
| car_name   |
| created_at |
| updated_at |
+------------+
```

I'm using Query Builder and my query:

```
DB::table('user')
   ->join('car', 'user.uid', '=', 'car.uid')
   ->where('user.uid', '=', $uid)
   ->get();
```

it truncated created_at and updated_at from car table and it gets me:

```
{
  "uid": 5,
  "name": "Alexander Lowe DVM",
  "created_at": "2017-04-01 18:12:45",
  "updated_at": "2017-04-01 18:12:45",
  "cid": 5,
  "car_name": "BMW X8",
}
```

And I want to make our query result become, How can I do this? Any solutions?

```
{
  "uid": 5,
  "name": "Alexander Lowe DVM",
  "created_at": "2017-04-01 18:12:45",
  "updated_at": "2017-04-01 18:12:45",
  "car": {
    "cid": 5,
    "car_name": "BMW X8",
    "created_at": "2017-04-01 18:12:45",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-01 18:12:45"
  }
}
```

.

Comment: You can use eloquent model and define relationships between them and get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what you get:

```
$users = DB::table('user')
            ->join('car', 'user.uid', '=', 'car.uid')
            ->where('user.uid', '=', $uid)
            ->select('user.*', 'car.created_at', 'car.updated_at')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use Eloquent > 2) Define Relationships

User.php

```
// for one to many relationship
   public function car() {
        return $this->hasMany(Car::class, 'uid');

//OR for one to one relationship
        return $this->hasOne(Car::class, 'uid');
    }
```

And for your query

```
User::with('car')->find($uid);
```

Comment: Can I do this without using eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

Define the below code in your User Model & find it automatically fetched in your query,

```
 public function car()
 {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Car');
    //return $this->hasMany('App\Car'); //Use this if user has multiple cars
 }
```

here is your query,

```
DB::table('user')
    ->where('user.uid', '=', $uid)
    ->with('car')
    ->get();
```

Also don't forget to define foreign key relationship

Comment: Can I do this without using eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a relation ship in model.

   ```
   public function car()
   { 
     return $this->hasOne('App\Car'); 
   }
   ```
2. Then use the `with()`

   ```
   user::where('uid', '=', $uid)->with('car')->get();
   ```